# PopupWindow crash on dispatch event

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, popupwindow

i have a trouble with PopupWindow android default widget. 
When i touch button to show popup and  than press back button on the phone, before popup was shown, i have force close message, the error is next:

```
    10-14 16:51:53.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer.dispatchKeyEvent(PopupWindow.java:1342)
            at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
            at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRoot.java:2431)
            at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1741)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So, after some tests i see, this bug is reproduces on android < 2.3 versions (2.1 , 2.2)
also i'm dig deep into the sources at grepcode, there is method:

```
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                    getKeyDispatcherState().startTracking(event, this);
                    return true;
                } else if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP
                        && getKeyDispatcherState().isTracking(event) && !event.isCanceled()) {
                    dismiss();
                    return true;
                }
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            } else {
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }
        }

    ...

        public KeyEvent.DispatcherState getKeyDispatcherState() {
            return mAttachInfo != null ? mAttachInfo.mKeyDispatchState : null;
        }
```

and method getKeyDispatcherState() return null

Does anyone have solved this problem?

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

The focus of this issue is you give focus to the Popupwindow before it is shown, so the dispatchevent will receive the back-key before your activity, but now your Popupwindow is not shown. You can test by not giving the focus to the Popupwindow and you will understand what I mean.

Comment: I am having the same issue and I have no clue who would be giving focus to popup windows. As in the original posters stack trace there are only android classes involved. We are not even showing the popupwindow explicitely (however we do use context menus which are shown just by default). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on android I believe.

Posted here:
http://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-aurora/rev/caca38771162